# I am getting Error saying "TypeError: callback is not a function"

Tags: javascript

Here is my code, I am getting Error saying "callback is undefined" and I am so confused that even though I have sent function as parameter to Search function it is considering it as an undefined.

```
    class Tree{
    constructor(){
        this.data;
        this.left;
        this.right;
    }
    Insert(data)
    {
       if(this.data)
       {
         if(this.data<data)
         {
             if(this.right)
             {
               this.right.Insert(data)
             }
             else{
                 this.right=new Tree();
                 this.right.Insert(data)
             }
         }
         else{
              if(this.left)
             {
               this.left.Insert(data)
             }
             else{
                 this.left=new Tree();
                 this.left.Insert(data)
             }
         }
       }
       else{
           this.data=data;
       }
    }
    Display(){
        if(this.left)
        {

            this.left.Display();
        }
        console.log(this.data);
        if(this.right)
        {   
            this.right.Display();
        }
    }
    Search(data,callback){

        if(data==this.data)
        {
            console.log("found")
            callback("found")
        }
        else if(data>this.data)
        {
            if(this.right)
            {
                this.right.Search(data);
            }
            else callback("not found")
        }
        else if(data<this.data){
            if(this.left)
            {
                this.left.Search(data);
            }
            else callback("not found")
        }
    }
}


var k =new Tree();
k.Insert(41);
k.Insert(34);
k.Insert(53);
k.Insert(384);
k.Search(34,function (res){
  console.log(res)
});
```

Could you guys help me on this? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Is the error really saying `Callback`, not `callback`?

Comment: /home/dhananjay/Desktop/Workspace/Trees/tree.js:43
            callback("found");
            ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at Tree.Search (/home/dhananjay/Desktop/Workspace/Trees/tree.js:54:13)
    at Tree.Search (/home/dhananjay/Desktop/Workspace/Trees/tree.js:67:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dhananjay/Desktop/Workspace/Trees/tree.js:80:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at loader (/home/dhananjay/Desktop/Workspace/Trees/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.j
s:144:5)

@FelixKling You are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `search` function You call `Serach` without `callback` parameter

```
Search(data,callback){

    if(data==this.data)
    {
        console.log("found")
        callback("found")
    }
    else if(data>this.data)
    {
        if(this.right)
        {
            this.right.Search(data, callback);
        }
        else callback("not found")
    }
    else if(data<this.data){
        if(this.left)
        {
            this.left.Search(data, callback);
        }
        else callback("not found")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,Worked well

Answer (score 3):

In this part

```
else if(data>this.data)
    {
        if(this.right)
        {
            this.right.Search(data);
        }
```

You don't send the call back, You should send the callback every time you call it.

***Solution***

```
else if(data>this.data)
    {
        if(this.right)
        {
            this.right.Search(data, callback);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, Worked well